# Data Type required in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I want to run several Association rule mining techniques such as Apriori, Eclat and FP Growth. I want to know the **format of the data** to run these algorithms as they are disabled (marked in grey)to me.

Also I don't see the algorithm **Eclat** in the 'Association' tab of Weka. Please recommend me a suitable tool/approach to perform this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to run several Association rule mining techniques such as
>   Apriori, Eclat and FP Growth. [...] Please recommend me a suitable
>   tool/approach to perform this

[Christian Borgelt's website](http://www.borgelt.net/fpm.html) offers several tools for frequent pattern mining:

- FPgrowth,
- Eclat,
- Apriori, and some others.

Check out the full descriptions to see how to use each one.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293121/what-are-data-requirements-for-fp-growth-in-weka) are some requirements for Weka's FPgrowth algorithm.